# Disable automatic system updates in Android One?

Tags: ota-update

Is there some hack which I can use to disable automatic check and installation of system updates on an Android One device? I have my device rooted and the automatic installation attempt breaks my Magisk > Restore images functionality as the partitions are locked for editing when the system_updater puts it to use. And then does not leave them free until reboot.

The developer options do have a setting regarding "Automatic System Updates". I did diable it, but all it stops is the Automatic application of the update when I reboot. That is, it does check for the updates, it does the verification and installation and then asks me to reboot. The only difference the toggle makes is that the device does not automatically change to the new slot when I reboot normally.

I am looking for something which can help me in postponing the check for updates until I manually tap on it. If that is too much, at least the update should not download and install without my permission. Google seems to be copying the annoying Windows 10 kind of update process for Android One now.

Comment: Have you tried of using a firewall app? I don't know which UID/app would be updating the phone, so I suggest using the firewall in whitelist mode and whitelisting absolutely only those items which you want to be connected to internet. May be this can atleast filter out the UID, after which you could try uninstalling or disabling the component. All of this is rather laborious though.

Comment: @Firelord Android One, hence updates are managed by Google Play Services app. I do not think I can keep it blocked via Firewall for long enough :( Plus my Firewall app will probably just get killed by some sorta battery saver :P